# Can I say "the table was covered by a scatter"?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say "the table was covered by a scatter"? Is it correct?

Comment: Probably not, but since I don't know what you mean by it, I can't tell for sure. Please explain.

Comment: @Noah, "scatter" indeed means a small amount of something or rather  a small amount of X. You need to substitute X with some word, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Alex B.- Right. I forgot to add that part. It should rather be *a scatter of something*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Of course you can say that...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. You have to say something like "the table was covered by a scatter of toys". It's just like "lot". You can say "the table was covered by a lot of junk", but you can't just say "the table was covered by a lot".

Here is some concrete evidence (besides my experience as a native English speaker) for this: the example phrases in two dictionaries.

- [*Merriam-Webster:*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatter) played before only a scatter of spectators in that huge stadium
- [*Oxford Dictionaries Online:*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scatter?region=us&q=scatter) a scatter of houses on the north shore

And here are the first Google hits for "covered by a scatter" (where "scatter" is not an adjective):

- covered by a scatter of cobble-stones
- covered by a scatter of limestone boulders
- covered by a scatter of medium-sized rocks
- covered by a scatter of debris
- covered by a scatter of limestone chips
- covered by a scatter of smaller boulders and pebbles
- covered by a scatter of burnt wattle and daub
- covered by a scatter of Chinese and Dutch trade porcelains
- covered by a scatter of round-edged boulders
- covered by a scatter of lights from homes, apartment houses, railways